# A algebric complication

Tags: linear-algebra, limits

Can anybody tell me that when do  we write $0^0 =1$ and when $0^0 = \text{indeterminate form} $. I want to use this notation in High school algebra.

Answer (score 0):

In general a limit like

$$
f(x)^{g(x)}
$$

where both $f$ and $g$ go to $0$, which is your $0^0$ form, depends on how rapidly $f(x)$ approaches $0$ relative to $g(x)$. You are better off solving your question another way than looking for some general rules.

For example, let's say we want to calculate $\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^x$. We can write this as $\lim_{x \to 0^+} e^{\ln(x)/\frac{1}{x}}$, then use l'Hopital's rule on $\ln(x)/\frac{1}{x}$ to get $\lim_{x\to 0^+} e^{-x}$, which is $1$.

Notice that here, l'Hopital's rule is used to compare whether the $\ln{x}$ term or the $x$ term is dominant when $x\to 0$.

Btw, you missed out one case. $\lim_{x \to 0^+} 0^x$ shows that the limit may also be $0$.